# Enable or Disable content inside an iframe

Tags: iframe, drupal-7

I have a page where the content comes from iframe. The issue is I want to hide a table column inside the iframe for users and display the same only for admin. Is it possible to toggle content that is displayed using iframe? If yes, please tell me how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the content displayed in the IFRAME provided by Drupal? If so depending on how that table created an access based visibility for that column could be accomplished. Either way, need more information about the iframe content.

Comment: No, the content inside iframe comes from .net code which is again from another domain. And the iframe contains some drop down selection options. After the selection is done a table is displayed with multiple rows and columns so from that table i want to hide a column for normal user and display it for admin.